# Multiple conditions in return reactjs

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I am creating a react project and I can not do multiple conditions when displaying
My component has a state like this:
{user
valid: "ok"
valid2: "ok"
}

In the return () I would like to add a condition to display "OK" if valid or valid2 is equal to ok
I tried something like this:

```
<p>
 {
   this.state.user.valid === "ok" || this.state.user.valid2 === "ok" ? "ok"
: "verify"
 }
</p>
```

But it does not work
How to do this please?

thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a return from render method?

Comment: Hav you tried parentheses around the condition of the ternary operator? Like `(this.state.user.valid === "ok" || this.state.user.valid2 === "ok") ? "Ok" : "verify"`

Comment: Yes that’s it !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if valid or valid2 is equal to ok. You need to add parentheses.

```
<p>
 { (this.state.valid === "ok" || this.state.valid2 === "ok")? "ok" : "verify" }
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{edit ? <component name /> : pedit ? <component name  />: <Default component name  />}
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please add an explanation of how this works and why it is supposed to help.